# Android tv-guid application

Tags: java, android

For an assignment I have to make an Android tv-guid app.
The assignment description states:

1. implement the program.java class according to the instructions in the ProgramInterface.java. Program.java is the datatype to describe programs.
2. implement the channel.java class according to the instructions in the ChannelInterface.java. Channel.java is the datatype to describe channels.
3. Implement the ChannelParser.java class according to the instructions in the ChannelParserInterface.java. ChannelParser.java is the object that reads the files and extracts the data to make an Arraylist of the channels.

I think i did workout the first two steps, but I can't get the last step working. Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong. I have attached all the codes.

ChannelInterface.java

```
public interface ChannelInterface {
/**
 * Method that returns the name of this channel, e.g. "Nederland 1".
 * @return  String channel name.
 */
public String getName();

/**
 * Method that returns the list of programs scheduled on this channel.
 * @return  ArrayList of Programs.
 */
public ArrayList<Program> getPrograms();

/**
 * Method to add a program to the list of programs.
 * @param program   The program that is to be added to the list.
 */
public void addProgram(Program program);
```

ChannelParserInterface.java

```
public interface ChannelParserInterface {

/**
 * Method invoked by the app to create the list of channels. This method should:
 *  - read the program details from file (txt/xml)
 *  - create the <code>ArrayList<Program></code> for each channel
 *  - create the Channel object for each channel (setting their name and program list)
 *  - return the list of create Channel objects.
 * Before returning the list of Channels, make sure that no gaps exist in the Program Lists of each channels (fill the gaps!).
 * @return  The ArrayList of Channels.
 */
public ArrayList<Channel> createChannels();
```

}

ChannelParser.java

```
public class ChannelParser implements ChannelParserInterface {

/**
 * Hulp methode om het bestand van internet in te lezen en als Stream aan te bieden.
 * @param type  "xml" of "txt" om aan te duiden welk bestand je wilt gebruiken
 * @return  De InputStream die gelezen kan worden.
 */
private InputStream openStream(String type) {
    try {
        URL url;

        if(type.equals("xml"))
            url = new URL("http://ict1.tbm.tudelft.nl/epg.xml");
        else
            url = new URL("http://ict1.tbm.tudelft.nl/epg.txt");

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        return con.getInputStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public ArrayList<Channel> createChannels() {
    ArrayList<Channel> result = new ArrayList<Channel>();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(openStream("txt"));

    ArrayList<Program> programlist = new ArrayList<Program>();

    Channel nederland1 = new Channel();
    Channel nederland2 = new Channel();
    Channel nederland3 = new Channel();
    Channel rtl4 = new Channel();
    Channel rtl5 = new Channel();
    Channel sbs6 = new Channel();
    Channel rtl7 = new Channel();
    Channel net5 = new Channel();
    Channel veronica = new Channel();
    Channel discovery = new Channel();


    result.add(new Channel());

    return result;
}
```

Program.java

```
public class Program implements ProgramInterface {

public String title, subtitle, description, category, startTime, endTime;

public Program(String title, String subtitle, String description, String category, String startTime, String endTime) {
    this.title = title;
    this.subtitle = subtitle;
    this.description = description;
    this.category = category;
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.endTime = endTime;
}


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getSubtitle() {
    return subtitle;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public String getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
}

public String getEndTime() {
    return endTime;
}
```

Channel.java

```
public class Channel implements ChannelInterface {
private String name;
private ArrayList<Program> programs;


public String getName() {
    return name;    //vergeet het return type niet
}

public ArrayList<Program> getPrograms() {
    return programs;
}
public void addProgram(Program program) {
    this.programs.add(program);
}
```

I get an error in the ChannelParser.java, because the Arraylist doesn't work, but I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: What is the stacktrace

Comment: I can't get the stack trace, because eclipse gives an error, which I don't understand, but the error I get is that: Program cannot be resolved to a type.
This is in line 45 of ChannelParser.java

Comment: You are missing an import clause?